# Is zfs on linux reliable enough to be installed with gentoo on a network attached storage?

Tags: linux, trim, hard-drive, gentoo, zfs

I have hard time to decide that which filesystem is the best and Raid or not Raid selection.  I have 4 different hard disk.
1. 120GB SSD 
2. 160GB
3. 500GB
4. 1TB

And I have noticed that zfs on linux does not support trim officially but third party patch, therefore, it is not fully tested....

As a result, I don't intend to let my ssd use zfs, I will use ext4 instead...

So, Is zfs on linux reliable enough to be installed with gentoo on a network attached storage?
Or you guys have another good solution for me?
P.S. if zfs is reliable enough, RAIDZ is a good choice?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Your question is of-topic here, but would be fine on [su] or [sf]. See [help/on-topic] for information about which questions are on-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your description you mention a set of disks you want to use. If you would use this set in e.g. RAIDZ and one disk crashes, your disk-array would lose all its data.

Reliability is a very broad expression;

If you want to protect your data agains bit-rot, then ZFS is an excellent choice.

If you would use it with your available disks and you would like to protect your data against hardware failures, consider using a more homogene set of disk.

Regarding your selection of OS, try OpenIndiana http://openindiana.org/ or some turn-key OS like http://www.freenas.org/ for relatively simple (but effective) configurations.

Comment: OpenIndiana is based on OpenSolaris which I haven't touched of.....     do you think it can perform well on network and file operation?

Comment: It performs really well; ZFS was developed by Sun for Solaris. This means that on Open Indiana has an native integration of ZFS. ZFS can also be used with SSDs as cache for your raid-set, this will improve the performance a lot.

Comment: Actually before I destroy my system, it was freenas. In my usage, it's too many bugs that it just shows something like "unexpected error". Therefore, I abandoned it... and finding a better system

Comment: In your case I would definitely go for a trial on OpenIndiana, there are webgui tools like Napp-it http://www.napp-it.org/ available to make it easier to work with. The free edition is probably sufficient for your NAS at home. Added to that; I would buy some cheap disks of the same size to generate some redundancy.

Answer (score 2):

Define "reliable enough".  If you're expecting bug-free operation, then no, it simply is not there yet.  If you're happy to potentially pick up the pieces from a total failure of the file system, then it's good enough.

If your data has any value and you're talking about a production machine, do not touch unproven file system drivers with a barge pole unless you know exactly what you're getting into.  A third-party patch for TRIM is definitely living on the edge.

If you desperately want to use ZFS, use FreeBSD where it is more mature.  If you're sticking with Linux, I would personally keep to ext4.  It's a solid system, and the drives you're talking about don't really demand the benefits of ZFS, in my opinion.

Comment: It seems use zfs on my situation is a bad idea, but xfs seems is worse compared to ext4, do you have any idea about that?

Answer (score 0):

Open Indiana is very reliable but a huge pain to run. FreeBSD has ZFS support built in. however (depending on what you are doing and how reliable you need) I would install it on Ubuntu if there is any margin for error.... if not.. then use Open Indiana or FreeBSD